# MySQL and PHP: Only the first field in the table is displayed

Tags: php, mysql, browser, html-table, field

I am working with PHP and MySQL. I need to retrieve all the rows from the database table and display on the browser in tabular form, but for some reason only the First field in the table gets displayed and others fields don't show up or are not pulled from the database.

Here is my PHP code.

```
<?php
include("DBConn.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM new_table");

if(!$result) {
  die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
}

echo "<table>
<caption>Signal Data:</caption>
<thead>
<tr>
   <th scope=\"col\">TagName:</th>  
  <th scope=\"col\">Enabled</th>  
  <th scope=\"col\">EU Value</th> 
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$tag = $row["TagName"];
$status = $row["Enabled"];
$Ev = $row["EUValue"];

echo "<tr>
 <th scope=\"row\">$tag</th>
 <td>$status</td>
 <td>$EV</td>
   </tr>";
}
echo  "</tbody></table>";
?>
```

What is wrong with this PHP code? The code itself executes fine without any error.

Comment: Side Note: Avoid `mysql` functions, they are no longer supported. Look into using `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: `$Ev` is not the same as `$EV` - Variables are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third row can be corrected by matching the case of the variable names. You are assigning the value to a variable named `$Ev` (lowercase 'v'):

```
$Ev = $row["EUValue"];
```

but attempting to use a variable named `$EV` (uppercase 'V'):

```
<td>$EV</td>
```

For both the second and third fields, ensure that `Enabled` and `EUValue` exactly match the names of the fields in your database, including case and spelling.

Finally, check the data itself to ensure that the fields have data in your database, and that the data is displayable in your HTML output.

Comment: Thanks... two of what you mentioned were true. Misspelling and No data.